# how to put fields from other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables A, B, and C, and they look like below.

```
A
id       x       y
-------------------
1        0       10
2        1       5
4        5       11
5        3       55

B
id       name    group_id
-------------------
1        QWE     10
2        KDF     10
4        AKS     11
5        LQK     13

C
group_id      group_name
------------------------
10            group1
11            group2
12            group3
13            group4
```

I want to combine these three into one table, so that it look like the following.

```
A
id       x       y       name    group_id    group_name
-------------------------------------------------------
1        0       10      QWE     10          group1
2        1       5       KDF     10          group1
4        5       11      AKS     11          group2
5        3       55      LQK     13          group4
```

I found some answers for merging columns from different tables, but I couldn't find any solution for looking up group_name on table C by group_id, and attaching it accordingly.

How can I do this?

Comment: You could use a full join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to JOIN your tables together:

```
SELECT
  A.id, A.x, A.y, B.name, B.group_id, C.group_name
FROM
  A INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
  INNER JOIN C ON B.group_id=C.group_id
```

you might also want to use a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN